# I Would Like To Replace A Word With A Letter In Python

Tags: python, replace

Code:

```
list = ['hello','world']
list2 = ['a','b']
string = 'hello'# should output a 
string_fin = ''
for s in string:
    for i, j in zip (list, list2):
        if s == i:
            string_fin += j
print(string_fin)
```

I want to write `hello or world` in `string = ''` and to get the output `a or b`

I get              which is nothing

The reason this is happening is because `hello and world` have more characters than `a and b` when I try something that has the same amount of characters as `a or b` it works

Please help

Thanks

Comment: As written, your `for` loops will never do anything.  There are no characters in an empty string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where the code says `for s in string:`, what values do you expect `s` to have each time through the loop? When you observe the actual behaviour of the code, what are the actual values of `s`? Are those values contained in `list`? Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, try to diagnose the underlying cause of the problem; and if you cannot fix it yourself, [search for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) a relevant existing question about fixing it. As a last resort, ask your own, *specific* question.

Comment: @PM77-1 I think the intent is that `string` represents hard-coded input to the code, which is changed to various values for testing. I agree that the code example should show the input `'hello or world'` (or similar), in that case.

Comment: What you WANT is `for s in string.split():`, so that `s` gets a word at a time, instead of a letter at a time.  It has nothing to do with the length of the words.  Also, you need to be adding in the original word if it is NOT in your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program's main loop never runs because `string` is empty! So your program is basically:

```
list = ['hello','world']
list2 = ['a','b']
string = ''
string_fin = ''
print(string_fin)
```

Although based on how you worded your question, it is really hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish, but here is my go.

- You have two lists: `list1` and `list2` (**Please do not name your list `list` as it is a reserved keyword, use `list1` instead!**)
- You want to check whether each word in your `string` matches with any word in your first list.
- If it matches you want to take the corresponding word or letter from your second list, and append it into the string `string_fin`.
- Finally, when you looped through all the words in the list, you print the content of `string_fin`.

The correct way to do this would be to split your `string` variable, and get each word stored in it.

```
string = 'hello or world'
stringWords = string.split()
```

Now, `stringWords` contains `['hello', 'or', 'world']`. But I think you are not interested in the item `or`. So you can remove this item from the list, by using `remove()`.

```
if 'or' in stringWords:
    stringWords.remove('or')
```

Now you have the words that you are interested in. And we want to check whether any word in the first list matches with these words. (Remember, I renamed the first list from `list` to `list1` to prevent any unexpected behavior.)

```
for word in stringWords:
    tempIndex = list1.index(word)
    temp = list2[tempIndex]
    string_fin += temp
```

However, using `index` raises `ValueError` if a match is not found, so depending on your program logic, you may need to catch an exception and handle it.
The string `string_fin` will now contain `ab` or `a` or `b` depending on the value inside `string`.

Now, since you wanted to print something like `a or b`, you can instead create a list and store the matching words in it, and then, join this list using `or` separator.

```
string_fin = (' or ').join(tempList)
```

A complete program now will look like this:

```
list1 = ['hello', 'world']
list2 = ['a', 'b']
string = 'hello or world'
tempList = []
stringWords = string.split()

if 'or' in stringWords:
    stringWords.remove('or')

for word in stringWords:
    tempIndex = list1.index(word)
    temp = list2[tempIndex]
    tempList.append(temp)

string_fin = ' or '.join(tempList)
print(string_fin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to store your lists as a dictionary, so you can do an easy lookup:

```
mapping = {'hello':'a', 'world':'b'}
string = 'hello or world'
out = []
for s in string.split():
    out.append( mapping.get( s, s ) )
print(' '.join(out))
```

Purists will note that the `for` loop can be made into a one-liner:

```
mapping = {'hello':'a', 'world':'b'}
string = 'hello or world'
out = ' '.join(mapping.get(s,s) for s in string.split())
print(out)
```